# According to Eastern Orthodoxy, can "co-parents-in-law" marry?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, marriage, canon-law

Same question as [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41600/can-co-parents-in-law-marry-for-example-a-husbands-father-and-a-wifes-mother) but for Eastern Orthodox. I don't see how a married couple's becoming step-siblings is any different from step-siblings' become a married couple.

Suppose Alice and Bob are widows (or single adoptive parents or unmarried biological parents or whatever) and their respective children are Charlie and Dalia. Suppose all 4 are not married (or were never married or whatever, depends if widow or not) and none of them have ever divorced or annulled.

If Alice and Bob marry, then (I think...) Charlie and Dalia cannot marry. But if Charlie and Dalia marry, then can Alice and Bob marry afterwards?

Comment: I'm digging into this a bit but inclined to say not. By the way, there's a word for this in Greek which may be helpful to you given your question is about Orthodoxy--sympather[os/a/oi] (masc/fem/plural)

Comment: @Alex in the catholic and even secular versions of this question, the answer is yes because APPARENTLY step-siblings can even marry. it's insane but at least it's consistent. I'd be pissed if they said step-siblings can't marry but a married couple can become step-siblings or if they said the reverse.